# Flask-SqlAlchemy: generating SQL with select function for materialized view

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to write a materialized view using SqlAlchemy's `select()` function and I am getting a `TypeError: 'DefaultMeta' object is not iterable`

The models are using `flask-sqlalchemy` and not plain `sqlalchemy`;

```
class Meta(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "meta"

    id = db.Column(UUID, primary_key=True)
    my_col = db.Column(db.String)
```

Right now I am testing to make sure I get the right sql statement in a view;

```
@app.route("/test", methods=["GET"])
def test():
    from sqlalchemy.sql import select, join,
    foo = select(Meta)
    return str(foo)
```

Expecting SQLAlchemy's equivalent to `SELECT * FROM meta`.

Comment: I believe my issue is that I am using Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.2.4 and SQLAlchemy==1.3.22 and the select function is changed in SQLAlchemy 1.4.  I'm upgrading now.

Answer (score 1):

I had to update to SQLAlchemy >= 1.4.